# How to implement only one table controller for all segment in pager?

Tags: ios, swift, pagination

I am implementing custom horizontal multiple segments with table view controller as content of each segment. But how to implement only one controller for all segments, because view is same for all segments but only  data is change.
I want to pass current index of segment to table view controller to get particular data.
I am using CAPSPageMenu.swift file from -https://codeload.github.com/uacaps/PageMenu/zip/master?

here is my code-

```
class Entrance_main_controller: UIViewController {

             var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?



override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // MARK: - UI Setup

    self.title = "Entrance Exam"

    // Initialize view controllers to display and place in array
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []



    let controller1 : Entrance_Content_ViewController =         Entrance_Content_ViewController(nibName: "TestTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    controller1.title = "Engineering"
    controllerArray.append(controller1)
    let controller2 : Entrance_Content_ViewController = Entrance_Content_ViewController(nibName: "TestTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    controller2.title = "Medical"
    controllerArray.append(controller2)

    let controller3 : Entrance_Content_ViewController = Entrance_Content_ViewController(nibName: "TestTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    controller3.title = "Management"
    controllerArray.append(controller3)

    // Customize menu (Optional)
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 30.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .ViewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 20.0/255.0, green: 20.0/255.0, blue: 20.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.orangeColor()),
        .BottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .MenuItemFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13.0)!),
        .MenuHeight(40.0),
        .MenuItemWidth(90.0),
        .CenterMenuItems(true)
    ]

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
    self.main_content_view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

    pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
 //here I am getting current index
func get_current_page() -> Int {
     let currentIndex = pageMenu!.currentPageIndex
    return currentIndex;
}

// MARK: - Container View Controller
override func shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

here I am using Entrance_Content_ViewController class for all segments.In this controller I am calling **get_current_page()** method for current page index.

```
class Entrance_Content_ViewController: UITableViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 let entrance_main_controller = Entrance_main_controller()
    let page = entrance_main_controller.get_current_page()
    print("page no\(page)")

    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "EntranceTableViewCell",        bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "EntranceTableViewCell")

        }
```

But I am getting this error- **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(lldb)**
Please help me to solve this problem.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea you can implement is, ***maintain array of data for each segment***. Then use switch over the segment index and as per segment index assign tableView DataSource.

The **rough code** should be like this:

```
switch(segmentIndex)
 {
   case: 0 yourDatasourceArray = segment0_DataArray
                :
                :
   //like this for all segments.
}
```

Comment: how can I get segment index in table view controller?

Comment: In your case it will be currentPageIndex.

Comment: first time I am getting index of page by adding this method main controller- func get_current_page() {
         let currentIndex = self.pageMenu!.currentPageIndex
        
        print("value in main\(currentIndex)")
    }

Comment: but when I call this method in table view controller i get this- fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That error means your optional is not assigned with proper value. Try to put debug points and check if your optional gets correct value or not.